# expected app structure and pathing problems after build of electron project using electron-forge

Tags: build, electron, electron-forge

I am creating a electron project and using electron-forge to package the application. I have the following electron folder project structure:

```
project:
  --|
    |-- binaries
    |-- src
    |-- node_modules
    |-- www
    |-- tmp
    |-- data
    |-- appCache
```

After build I want the following folder structure of electron:

```
project:
  --|
    |-- binaries
    |-- locales
    |-- resources
    |       |--- app.asar
    |               app.asar> |-- node_modules
    |               app.asar> |-- www
    |               app.asar> |-- src
    |-- tmp
    |-- data
    |-- appCache
```

I just have three questions.

1. How do I pack the folders into app.asar, unpack it for usage OR How do I put the folders into the resources folder during build
2. How do I ensure tht the pathing issue does not happen during runtime since while development the folder structure is different and after packaging/ making electron executable the folder structure is different
3. What is the command to build for all architecture and platforms

I am using electron forge to build the electron project.